# Search Item in RecyclerviewMergeAdapter with different adapter in one recyclerview

Tags: java, android-studio, search, android-recyclerview

i have some code with use plugin RecyclerViewMergeAdapater in here
https://github.com/martijnvdwoude/recycler-view-merge-adapter...
then i want to make search function in that, but it not working both only one adapter working, else adapter not working...

here my code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_chat, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            if (!newText.trim().isEmpty()) {
                RealmResults<User> users = RealmHelper.getInstance().searchForUser(newText, false);
                mergeAdapter.containsAdapter(new UsersAdapter(users, true, NewChatActivity.this));
                rvNewChat.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);
            } else {
                mergeAdapter.containsAdapter(new UsersAdapter(userList, true, NewChatActivity.this));
                rvNewChat.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);
            }

            inviteAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }

    });
```

i hope result of search 2 adapter is working...
has anyone ever used it?

Comment: What is containsAdapter

Comment: i have experient for that, because in the documentation of RecyclerViewMergeAdapter there is function contains adapter... actually that's is not working... the method that works is inviteAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText); and that for search in the other adapter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply search results to your MergeAdapter, I would iterate over the list of adapters you added to your MergeAdapter and filter out items matching your criteria. Once these items are filtered out you could submit them back to the adapter.

1. In the example below I stored them in a map called **internalAdapterRegistry**.

   private val internalAdapterRegistry = mutableMapOf<String, YourAdapter>()
2. Assuming that we are looking for a match in the list of Products (your custom data class):

   data class Product(var product_name: String, var product_quantity: Int)

```
     override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu)

        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = searchItem?.actionView as SearchView

        searchView.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.search_src_text).threshold = 3
        searchView.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object :
            SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                fun filter(text: String) {
                    val textSearch = text.toLowerCase()
                    if (textSearch.isNotEmpty()){
                        for (adapter in internalAdapterRegistry) {
                            val listOfYourItems = adapter.value.currentList
                            adapter.value.submitList(listOfYourItems.filter { product -> product.product_name.contains(textSearch, ignoreCase = true) })
                        }
                    }
                }
                filter(newText)
                return false
            }
        })
```

3. If you want to make it work when your are removing characters from your search bar, you will need to store **currentList** in a separate variable. I did not implement it here. Just wanted to give you an idea how you can play this one.